# angularjs ng-show multiple divs and clean unselected model values

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ng-show, angular-ng-if

I have input field with dropdown values: A, B, ... Z, referred to as `ng-model=model.all`.
I want to `ng-show` another `<div>` if the value of `ng-model=model.all` is equal to `Option Z`. This part is working fine.
But the question is: 
How can I show the **Acat** `<div>` ONLY if any other value except **Option Z** is chosen from the first one? I tried `ng-show="model.all != 'Option Z'` , but it shows the `<div>` even when nothing is selected. It just need to show the other div ONLY IF something other than   **Option Z** is selected.

As you can see, my **Bcat** is shown only if the **Acat** is not empty, which is alright.
 But, if I change my selection in the first one and choose **Option Z**, then the other two divs still hold their values, so the goal is to clean them if **Option Z** is selected, and vice versa, if something else is selected and accordingly, the other divs are populated with values, and if user decides to change the selection and choose **Option Z** then those values in previous divs should be cleaned as well.

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">ALL</label>
    <ui-select ng-model="model.all" name="all">
        ...
    </ui-select>
</div>


<div class="form-group" ng-show="model.all == 'Option Z'">
    <label>Z categories</label>
    <ui-select name="Zcat" ng-model="model.z">
        ...
    </ui-select>    
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-show="???">
    <label class="control-label">Category A</label>
    <ui-select name="Acat" ng-model="model.a">
        ...
    </ui-select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-show="!model.a">
    <label class="control-label">Category B</label>
    <ui-select name="Bcat" ng-model="model.b" >
        ...
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

### update:

just a short note to add after Mosh Feu's answer:
As you can see here in screenshot https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9mYH.jpg , this should never happen.
 Either, I pass the 
`{"all": "Option Z", "z": "Option Z1"}`
 or 
`{"all": "Option A", "a": "Option A1", "b": "Option B1"}` .
 This is not accepted:  
`{"all": "Option A", "a": "Option A1", "b": "Option B1", "z": "null"}`  
nor this one :
 `{"all": "Option Z", "z": "Option Z1", "a": "null", "b": "null"}`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this might work for you:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">ALL</label>
    <ui-select ng-model="model.all" ng-change="onModelChange()" name="all">
        ...
    </ui-select>
</div>


<div class="form-group" ng-show="model.all == 'Option Z'">
    <label>Z categories</label>
    <ui-select name="Zcat" ng-model="model.z">
        ...
    </ui-select>    
</div>

<div class="form-group" ng-show="!!model.all && model.all != 'Option Z'">
    <label class="control-label">Category A</label>
    <ui-select name="Acat" ng-model="model.a">
        ...
    </ui-select>
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-show="!!model.a && model.all != 'Option Z'">
    <label class="control-label">Category B</label>
    <ui-select name="Bcat" ng-model="model.b" >
        ...
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

and here is the controller bit:

```
$scope.onModelChange = function(){
    if ($scope.model.all) {
        $scope.model.z = "";
        $scope.model.a = "";
        $scope.model.b = "";
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

May this will help you you have just to need add ng-change with your select form

```html
<html ng-app="myapp">
 <!-- Body tag augmented with ngController directive  -->
 <body ng-controller="MyController">
 
 <form name="myForm">
    <label for="singleSelect"> All </label><br>
    <select name="singleSelect" ng-model="catselect" ng-change="cat()">
      <option value="a">Acat</option>
      <option value="b">Bcat</option>
   <option value="z">Zcat</option>
    </select><br>
 
 

  </form>
 
 <div ng-show="ashow" >This is Acat Div</div>
 <div ng-show="bshow">This is Bcat Div</div>
 <div ng-show="zshow">This is Zcat Div</div>
 
      
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.0/angular.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript">
 var app = angular.module('myapp',[]);
 app.controller("MyController", ["$scope", function($scope) { 
 
 // you can also get this data from external-json-object
 
 
 $scope.ashow = true;
 $scope.bshow = true;
 $scope.zshow = true;
 
 
  

    $scope.cat = function(){

  if($scope.catselect == "z"){
  $scope.ashow = false;
  }else{
   $scope.ashow = true;
 $scope.bshow = true;
 $scope.zshow = true;
  }
 } 
}]);
   </script>
   
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you need to check if `model.all` is selected **and** it's not equals to `Option Z`. If so, the check is simple:

```js
// !!model.all - to check if anything selected
!!model.all && model.all != 'Option Z'
```

About the second part. When the `select` changed and the value is `Option Z` just set the `a` and the `b` to `null` (See it in the code).

I hope that I answered you on all the pieces but if not, let me know.

Note: You can also see the model in the `pre`.

```js
angular.module('myApp', []).
controller('ctrl', function() {
  var model = this;
  
  model.shouldShowACat = function() {
    return !!model.all && model.all != 'Option Z';
  };
  
  model.clearAB = function() {
    if (model.all == 'Option Z') {
      model.a = null;
      model.b = null;
    }
  };
});
```

```css
pre {
  background: silver;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="ctrl as model">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">ALL</label>
    <select ng-model="model.all" name="all" ng-change="model.clearAB()">
      <option>Option A</option>
      <option>Option B</option>
      <option>Option Z</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" ng-show="model.all == 'Option Z'">
    <label>Z categories</label>
    <select name="Zcat" ng-model="model.z">
      <option>Option Z1</option>
      <option>Option Z2</option>
    </select>    
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" ng-show="model.shouldShowACat()">
    <label class="control-label">Category A</label>
    <select name="Acat" ng-model="model.a">
      <option>Option A1</option>
      <option>Option A2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group" ng-show="!model.a">
    <label class="control-label">Category B</label>
    <select name="Bcat" ng-model="model.b" >
      <option>Option B1</option>
      <option>Option B2</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <pre ng-bind="model | json"></pre>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. But is it possible NOT to pass even the `null` value to the unselected option. By the way, there is a serious error in the code, as you might guess, here is the screenshot http://imgur.com/gSYztLq this should never happen. Either, I pass the `{"all": "Option Z", "z": "Option Z1"}` or `{"all": "Option A", "a": "Option A1", "b": "Option B1"}` . This is not accepted:  `{"all": "Option A", "a": "Option A1", "b": "Option B1", "z": "null"}`  nor this one : `{"all": "Option Z", "z": "Option Z1", "a": "null", "b": "null"}`, i hope this is clear.

Answer (score 1):

You can use ng-change event and ng-if. Refer below

**html**

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label class="control-label">ALL</label>
    <ui-select ng-model="model.all" name="all" ng-change="populateCatA()">
        ...
    </ui-select>
</div>

// I used ng-if here, so that the dom is removed, not hidden 
<div class="form-group" ng-if="showCatA">
    <label class="control-label">Category A</label>
    <ui-select name="Acat" ng-model="model.a">
        ...
    </ui-select>
</div>
```

**Js Controller**

```
$scope.showCatA = false;
var populateCatA = function () {
    if ($scope.model.all != 'Option Z') {
         $scope.showCatA = true;
    } else {
         $scope.showCatA = false;
    }
}
```